# Same Jbutton selected state across multiple instances of same JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a toggle JButton that, when clicked, either installs or uninstalls some listeners elsewhere (but that's somewhat irrelevant I believe, as it could be just about any code that you don't want executed any number of times in a row, hence, the toggle, you click it once, it does something, you click it again, it undoes that something or whatever). My problem is that I have several instances of this button (or more specifically, several instances of its parent JPanel). **This restriction is not my doing and I cannot prevent this.** Basically, I'm left with a situation where the user can toggle the button "on" a bunch of times in succession, and needless to say, this screws things up for me.

The buttons themselves are not all visible to the user at once, only one can be seen at any given time. I tried using a component listener, but componentHidden() and componentShown() are never called.

I tried making the button a singleton, but that just had this weird effect of only displaying the button on the last panel it was added to.

I'm kinda stumped. The behaviour I want is simple: Multiple instances of this toggle button that sync their selected state. Ideas?

P.S. I suppose I could construct a list of the instances and update all the other's state when one of them is clicked, but I wonder if there's something simpler out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No big reveal here. I solved my problem using my own suggestion, that is, I simply kept a list of all the instances of the button and set their states when any one of them was clicked in an action they all share.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the buttons must all be distinct, but they can either share the same ButtonModel or the same Action. Usually, I try to have them share Actions by creating a single Action that extends AbstractAction, and use it to set the Actions of all the same buttons.

Comment: They do share the same action, that's part of the problem. Oh I suppose I could set and check some static state variable, and that would solve my problem, but as far is the user is concerned, each instance of this button appears to be the same button, so the toggle state needs to be synced, otherwise it just looks like poor GUI design (which it prolly is, but that's something I can't change).

Comment: @brock: `"They do share the same action, that's part of the problem."` -- If the code still doesn't work despite sharing actions or models, then for better help, we'll all be best served if you could create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Either I have failed to explain myself properly or you have misunderstood my problem or both. Forgive me if I'm absolutely wrong here (I'm not a Swing guru by any stretch), but I can't use ButtonModel because I need to use JButton so, when toggled, it simply looks like a regular button that stays pushed, not a checkbox or radio. All I need to do is sync the state of all instances of this one button... And I did it using my own suggestion.

Comment: @brock: Thanks for the update. My own opinion is that the error of omission is that you did not post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as was requested, since without the small working example, it was hard for us to fully understand just what the problem was. I still cannot tell whether sharing actions would or would not work and fear that your current solution may be brittle, but again without more code, it's hard to tell.